# Git squash all commits in branch without conflicting

Tags: git, rebase, squash

A common development workflow for us is to checkout branch `b`, commit a bunch to it, then squash all those commits into one (still on `b`).

However, during the `rebase -i` process to squash all the commits, there are frequently conflicts at multiple steps.

**I essentially want to alter the branch into one commit that represents the state of the repository at the time of the final commit on `b`**

I've done some searching but I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for. I don't want to `merge --squash` because we would like to test the squashed feature branch before merging.

Comment: From that question - I do not want `G` to be in `stable`, I want it to still be on the feature branch. Not sure if i'm missing something

Comment: Couldn't you just cherry-pick `G` then?

Comment: Cherry pick it on what branch? I would like to keep the same branch name

Comment: Why would there be conflicts when squashing? That doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you don't need the commit information, then you could just do a soft reset. Then files remain as they were and when you commit, this commit will be on top of the commit you did reset to.

To find the commit to reset to:

```
git merge-base HEAD BRANCH_YOU_BRANCHED_FROM
```

Then

```
git reset --soft COMMIT_HASH
```

Then re-craft the commit, perhaps:

```
git commit -am 'This is the new re-created one commit'
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for this. Can you please explain why this doesn't work when you do just a "reset" (without --soft)?

Comment: Default is `--mixed` instead of `--soft`. Mixed will reset the index and HEAD. Soft will only reset the HEAD. Hard reset will reset WorkingDir + Index + HEAD

Answer (score 10):

This is simlar to the answer from Rasmus but broken down into three steps that should always work:

```
$ git merge feature1
$ git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
$ git commit -c feature1
```

Explanation:

1. merge and resolve conflicts
2. keep changes staged but reset to old head
3. commit all changes using commit message and author from feature branch latest commit

Answer (score 4):

I've created a tool specifically for this task:

https://github.com/sheerun/git-squash

For example you can call following to squash all commits from "master" commit up to HEAD, no matter how many conflicts there would be along the way:

```
git squash master
```

It's basically what GitHub does when you "squash and merge" pull request.

Comment: This is really what I was looking for. Thanks.