# Lost changes during squash with rebase

Tags: git, rebase, git-squash

I try to run

> git rebase -i HEAD~N

to squash my older commits into one. But sometimes I got a Merge conflict. The problem is, even if I resolve the conflict and do a "git rebase --continue", I lost a lot of my other commit changes.

I also tried to solve the issue based on these answers: [Git squash all commits in branch without conflicting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354353/git-squash-all-commits-in-branch-without-conflicting)

Comment: 2 questions : 1. did you by any chance change the order in which the commits are applied, or delete any commit ? 2. is there a merge commit in the last `N` commits you are trying to squash together ?

Comment: 1. no, what I did is to make some pushes where I successfully squashed the first 35 commit (and I still have 11)
2. Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using rebase for squashing by using reset --soft. Say you want yo squash from HEAD~100 up to your current branch (HEAD~100 being the last surviving commit that won't be squashed):

```
git reset --soft HEAD~100
git commit -m "Squashed stuff"
```

And that's it. No conflicts, no hassles.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to rebase a range of commits which includes a merge commit, add the `-m` option :

```
git rebase -i -m HEAD~N
```

The sequencer script will allow you to describe how you include that merge in the rewriting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried it, but unfortunately it behaved in the same way as I tried it at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Soft reset is worked, but I found a better solution. The problem was that there was already a merge commit within the commits which I wanted to squash. I used the following code to get the parent commit:

```
git show --pretty=%P COMMIT_HASH
```

Finally, I had to use the parent commit's hash to do the rebase.